# Place 2 sets of columns adjacent to each other in stacked mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working on changing a website over to a responsive design and am using Bootstrap 4. Currently, I have 4 columns in a row that look good on larger screens (I'm using col-sm for these), but when they switched to stacked mode, there is a lot of whitespace that I would like to fill with the columns.

The relevant part in my HTML:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 offset-md-2">
    <b>CVV2 Code</b>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_cc_ccv2_reqd" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <sup><a onclick="javascript: window.open('/Images/CVV2CodeHelp.GIF', 'myWin', 'toolbar=no, directories=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, scrollbars=no, width=570, height=160'); return false;"
                href="#">Help</a></sup>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_cc_ccv2_err" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small"></asp:Label>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_cc_ccv2" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" MaxLength="4" autocomplete="off" columns="6" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <b>Billing ZIP code</b>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_cc_zipcode_reqd" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_cc_zip_err" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small">
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_cc_zip" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" MaxLength="5" autocomplete="off" Columns="6" />
  </div>
</div>
```

So, I have the 4 columns that look something like this:

```
CVV2 Code     [       ]       Billing Zip Code     [          ]
```

And I would like to make them look more like this when it switches to stacked mode:

```
CVV2 Code        Billing Zip Code
[        ]       [          ]
```

Is there a way to do this in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col-sm` is specifically for small screens, with `col-md` being used for tablets and above.

Assuming you want to display your four elements in one line for desktops and have them stacked onto two lines for mobiles, what you're looking to do is swap all of your existing classes to be `md` instead of `sm`, and then make use of four `col-sm-6` classes:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 offset-md-2">
    <b>CVV2 Code</b>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_cc_ccv2_reqd" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <sup><a onclick="javascript: window.open('/Images/CVV2CodeHelp.GIF', 'myWin', 'toolbar=no, directories=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, scrollbars=no, width=570, height=160'); return false;"
            href="#">Help</a></sup>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_cc_ccv2_err" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small">Blank</asp:Label>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_cc_ccv2" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" MaxLength="4" autocomplete="off" columns="6" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    <b>Billing ZIP code</b>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_cc_zipcode_reqd" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_cc_zip_err" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small">Blank
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_cc_zip" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" MaxLength="5" autocomplete="off" Columns="6" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I've also put `Blank` in the ASP segments, to show where they get positioned.

*However*, assuming you want to swap the positioning so that the ASP components line up below their respective labels for mobile devices, that's quite a bit more complicated. You'll have to change the structure so that each pair of elements forms an independent row, nesting rows within rows.

The outer columns should both occupy half of the width at both `sm` and `md`, and the inner columns should take up the full width for `sm`, but only half the width at `md`.

You can still have the offset of `offset-md-2` on the first **outer** column, though you'll need to couple this with `col-md-4` (as the second outer column is `col-md-6`, and the columns need to total 12).

Note that after clicking 'Run snippet', you can click on 'Full page' to see the layout change in effect.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 offset-md-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <b>CVV2 Code</b>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_cc_ccv2_reqd" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <sup><a onclick="javascript: window.open('/Images/CVV2CodeHelp.GIF', 'myWin', 'toolbar=no, directories=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, scrollbars=no, width=570, height=160'); return false;"
            href="#">Help</a></sup>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_cc_ccv2_err" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small">Blank</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_cc_ccv2" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" MaxLength="4" autocomplete="off" columns="6" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <b>Billing ZIP code</b>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_cc_zipcode_reqd" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_cc_zip_err" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small">Blank
        </asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_cc_zip" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" MaxLength="5" autocomplete="off" Columns="6" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: That did almost what I needed. I wanted the columns to appear the same way on xs devices, so I just changed all the col-sm-* to col-* and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved with embedded `.row`s and `.col`s like that:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-5 offset-md-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <b>CVV2 Code</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                [ ]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <b>Billing ZIP code</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                [ ]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

*Please note, that I have removed the `<asp>` tag in order to have a cleaner example, but that does not change the essence.*

Answer (score 0):

I just applied Grid to get the desired result.

```css
.lab {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 lab">Label 1</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 text">Text 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 lab">Label 2</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 text">Text 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can omit the CSS and add your HTML at desired placed.